# how to make a javascript function wait to finish websql transactions before continuing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to do a very simple task of finding out which websql table has the row with the latest date. I am trying to use the jquery deferred to help me do that, but for some reason its just not working.

There are two platform tables, FORUM and BLOG. The following code gets the latest post date for each platform, and then is supposed to see which one is newer and set a global variable window.lastplatform to either 'blog' or 'forum'.

I have been trying all kinds of things and methods but nothing seems to work.

```
function lastPlatform()
{
    $.when( setLastPostDates ).then( setLastPlatform(), alert('failed') );
}

function setLastPlatform()
{
    var blogYear = window.lastblogpostdate.substring(0, 4);
    var blogMonth = window.lastblogpostdate.substring(5, 7);
    var blogDay = window.lastblogpostdate.substring(8, 10);
    var blogHours = window.lastblogpostdate.substring(11, 13);
    var blogMinutes = window.lastblogpostdate.substring(14, 16);
    var blogSeconds = window.lastblogpostdate.substring(17);

    var forumYear = window.lastforumpostdate.substring(0, 4);
    var forumMonth = window.lastforumpostdate.substring(5, 7);
    var forumDay = window.lastforumpostdate.substring(8, 10);
    var forumHours = window.lastforumpostdate.substring(11, 13);
    var forumMinutes = window.lastforumpostdate.substring(14, 16);
    var forumSeconds = window.lastforumpostdate.substring(17);

    lastblogpostdate = new Date(blogYear, blogMonth, blogDay, blogHours, blogMinutes, blogSeconds);
    lastforumpostdate = new Date(forumYear, forumMonth, forumDay, forumHours, forumMinutes, forumSeconds);
    if (lastblogpostdate > lastforumpostdate) {
        window.lastplatform = 'blog';
    } else {
        window.lastplatform = 'forum';
    }
}

function setLastPostDates() 
{
    if(!db){
        db=window.openDatabase("postdb","1.0","Posts",200000);
    }

    db.transaction(queryLastBlogPostDate,errorCB);
    db.transaction(queryLastForumPostDate,errorCB);
}

function queryLastBlogPostDate(tx)
{
    tx.executeSql('SELECT post_date FROM BLOG ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 1',[], function(tx, results){
        window.lastblogpostdate = results.rows.item(0).post_date;
        alert(window.lastblogpostdate);
    },errorCB);
}

function queryLastForumPostDate(tx)
{
    tx.executeSql('SELECT post_date FROM FORUM ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 1',[],     function(tx, results){
        window.lastforumpostdate = results.rows.item(0).post_date;
        alert(window.lastforumpostdate);
    },errorCB);
}
```

I would appreciate any kind of info, tips or help.

Comment: Quick hint: you are *calling* your `setLastPlatform` instead of just *passing* it. I also don't see that defined anywhere.

Comment: fixed the code. How can I just pass the setLastPlatform() function in this case?

Comment: Don't call it: `function_name` *is* the function, `function_name()` *calls* it. (Remove parens.) You should also accept the result as an argument instead of using `window.lastforumpostdate` to pass it. I think you may need a [basic tutorial on promises and deferreds](http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/).

Comment: Ok thanks for your tips. I have read the page you linked and it starts to make more sense. I guess I will just have to read the reference until I get it fully. Deferred is a new principle for me as I mostly use basic JS snippets and hack them up together to get something working without really knowing whats going on.